# To add a new column in the external list

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, external-content-type, external-list, external-data-column

I have created external list to retrieve SQL data into my SharePoint via External Content Type (ECT). Everything working fine till here but the problem is when ever i want to add a new column to the External list.

So to add a new column in the external list i am doing the following 3 things every time.

1. Adding a column by altering SQL table
2. Remove existing operations in the existing External content type and reconnect to the table to get the new column into ECT>
3. Remove the existing external list and recreate to get the new column.

By doing the above 3 things i am loosing the custom forms (Edit, New, Display) which are associated to my external list.

Can someone please advice how can i modify my external list with a new column with out disturbing my external list custom forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to delete the existing external list and recreate one. In the existing list, just modify the view and add the new column to your view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael....It's working and saved my time.